# Limit of a sequence :

Tags: limits, radicals, means

How do I compute the following limit

$$ \lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left  (\frac { \sqrt [ n ]{ a } +\sqrt [ n ]{ b } +\sqrt [ n ]{ c } +\sqrt [ n ]{ d }  }{ 4 } \right ) }^{ n } }  $$

$a,b,c,d\geq0$

Thanks.

Comment: People usually include the attempts they've made at solving a problem. It increasing the chance of getting help because it's a lot easier to point out what your doing wrong if you include this information.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ real non-negative numbers?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531831/why-is-the-0th-power-mean-defined-to-be-the-geometric-mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $n=\dfrac{1}{m}$ and we have:

$$\lim_{m\to 0}\left(\frac{a^m+b^m+c^m+d^m}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$

This is actually the geometric mean of $a,b,c,d$.

**Proof:** taking the logarithm, we investigate:

$$\lim_{m\to 0}\dfrac{1}{m}\ln\left(\frac{a^m+b^m+c^m+d^m}{4}\right)$$

Use l'Hopital's treating $m$ as a variable:

$$\lim_{m\to 0}\left(\frac{\ln a\cdot a^{m}+\ln b\cdot b^{m}+\ln c\cdot c^{m}+\ln d\cdot d^{m}}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4}{a^{m}+b^{m}+c^{m}+d^{m}}\right)$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{4}(\ln a+\ln b+\ln c+\ln d)=\ln (abcd)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Exponentiate and we get the desired result:

$$\lim_{m\to 0}\left(\frac{a^m+b^m+c^m+d^m}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}=(abcd)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: I think that L'hopital's rule can't be applied to sequences, [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/sequences.html)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for helping!.

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the elementary limits $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n=e$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} (a^x-1)/x=\ln a, \space a>0$, we get

$$\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ e^{ \left  (\displaystyle n \frac { \sqrt [ n ]{ a } +\sqrt [ n ]{ b } +\sqrt [ n ]{ c } +\sqrt [ n ]{ d }-4  }{ 4 } \right ) } }={ e^{\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty  } \sum_{abcd} (t^{1/n}-1)/(1/n)}}=(abcd)^{\frac{1}{4}}.$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: hmm ... could you elaborate it?

Comment: @experimentX: I used $\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left  (1+\frac { \sqrt [ n ]{ a } +\sqrt [ n ]{ b } +\sqrt [ n ]{ c } +\sqrt [ n ]{ d }  }{ 4 } -1\right ) }^{ n } }=\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty  }\left({ { \left  (1+\frac { \sqrt [ n ]{ a } +\sqrt [ n ]{ b } +\sqrt [ n ]{ c } +\sqrt [ n ]{ d } -4 }{ 4 } \right ) }^{ \displaystyle\frac { 4}{ \sqrt [ n ]{ a } +\sqrt [ n ]{ b } +\sqrt [ n ]{ c } +\sqrt [ n ]{ d } -4  } } }\right)^{n\displaystyle\frac { \sqrt [ n ]{ a } +\sqrt [ n ]{ b } +\sqrt [ n ]{ c } +\sqrt [ n ]{ d } -4 }{ 4 }}$

Comment: very clever ...

Comment: @experimentX: thank you. I only used those basic limits I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you show all the steps please?