# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{3^\frac{1}{n}+4^\frac{1}{n}+5^\frac{1}{n}}{3})^n$

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{3^\frac{1}{n}+4^\frac{1}{n}+5^\frac{1}{n}}{3})^n$

Sorry, I forget how to compute the limit, can anyone gives a hint, thanks a lot.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505093/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397376/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20(%5Cfrac%7B3%5E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%2B4%5E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%2B5%5E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%7B3%7D)%5En%24)

Comment: @MartinR thanks, the resources you give help me a lot. Thanks!