# Find this: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left [ \frac{a_{1}^{x}+a_{2}^{x}+a_{3}^{x}+\dots+a_{n}^{x}}{n} \right ]^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

Sorry if I make something wrong in this post, because it is my first post.

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left [ \frac{a_{1}^{x}+a_{2}^{x}+a_{3}^{x}+\dots+a_{n}^{x}}{n} \right ]^{1/x}
$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: @abiessu I'm trying to solve this by number "e", but I can't. What are your suggesions, any method?

Comment: You must be assuming all $a_k \geq 0$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531831/why-is-the-0th-power-mean-defined-to-be-the-geometric-mean

Comment: Are there any rrstrictions about $x$ and $a_j$?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland is there any way you know expect assuming? By the way, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @ExpikQwg I don't understand the sentence "is there any way you know expect assuming?"

Comment: @ByronSchmuland do you know any other way to solve this limit expect this one with L'Hospital's rule (link you posted). Thank you.

Comment: @ExpikQwg You want the word "except", not "expect". I'm sorry, I don't know any other way.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland sorry for that mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

"Shortcut":

If

$\lim_{x→α}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x→α}g(x)= \infty $

then $$\lim_{x→α}(f(x))^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}(1+f(x)−1)^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}[[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{(f(x)-1)}]^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}= e^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}.$$ 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left [ \frac{a_{1}^{x}+a_{2}^{x}+a_{3}^{x}+\dots+a_{n}^{x}}{n} \right ]^{1/x}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\dfrac{a_{1}^{x}-1}{x}+\dfrac{a_{2}^{x}-1}{x}+ \cdots +\dfrac{a_{n}^{x}-1}{x})}=e^{\frac{1}{n}(\ln a_1+\ln a_2+ \cdots +\ln a_n)}= e^{\ln (a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}= (a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

We applied $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{a^{x}-1}{x}= \ln a.$

Comment: Still can't understand. By the way thank you